# How to fix "{"error":"Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0","version":"1.3.0"}"

Tags: python, json

I just want to make auto making thread / creating list. I just checked in console, the error says

> "{"error":"Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0","version":"1.3.0"}".

How can I resolve this error?

The Python Code:

```py
import requests
from io import BytesIO

headers = {
    'authority': 'traderie.com',
    'method': 'POST',
    'path': '/api/adopt_me/listings/create',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'authorization': 'Bearer ',
    'content-length': '722',
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarypqN01X2kArSkOHBn',
    'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.850822138.1642224893; _gid=GA1.2.556027755.1642224893; usprivacy=1---; ad_clicker=false; _pw_fingerprint=6818da724c1a866373d3104d2cd082e4; _gcl_au=1.1.628091182.1642224893; _hjid=cc106801-cff3-4156-afad-2b5845f96325; _hjSessionUser_2441420=eyJpZCI6IjQyMjdmMjVjLWEyMjItNTI1Ny04NjUwLWY3MmU1NjEyYjNlZiIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDIyMjQ4OTMyMDAsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; _hjSession_2441420=eyJpZCI6ImVkODE1MDc5LTYwNWItNDIzMC1iODUxLWZkOGRlNmM2YjM3MCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDIyMjQ4OTM0MzEsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _pw_audience_segments=["1","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]; __stripe_mid=a848c4df-5112-4afd-8bdd-2235857cc00abc7ef9; __stripe_sid=e1c6337b-f03f-4b93-8441-eb1d118cee58001fb3; _pw_audience_categories=["games_hardcore"]; _pbjs_userid_consent_data=3524755945110770; pwUID=369796799639702; __gads=ID=dcb867edd8f2877b:T=1642224926:S=ALNI_MYArRYYa1oDgieG9f1YFUuJjVv-oQ; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; G_AUTHUSER_H=2; _gat_UA-176465218-1=1; _gat_gtag_UA_176465218_1=1; cto_bundle=5p2Tj182VmVrbFhLNUFmS3lZNXllZnk2b1UzbkYwR0JhVUFUMSUyRnplYWd1QWh1VyUyQmlrJTJGYjlOTU1XdE1xb050NjhHJTJCajczQW1MeDNQSnRoRG9tM2UzeHN1blk5Z2pHYllDUlJLQUxVUHVDclp1JTJGT0N6cHluWjdjZzRGNVdRZFhqeUJiQmZSZlVORnI0dGlhdnV4MDQ2YnZFeVVnJTNEJTNE; playwirePageViews=16',
    'origin': 'https://traderie.com',
    'referer': 'https://traderie.com/adoptme/product/1276977709',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}

body = '{"acceptListingPrice":false,"currencyGroupPrices":[],"diy":false,"endTime":"","free":false,"item":"1276977709","itemType":"pets","makeOffer":true,"needMaterials":false,"offerBells":false,"offerNmt":false,"offerWishlist":false,"offerWishlistId":"","selling":true,"standingListing":false,"stockListing":false,"touchTrading":false,"wishlist":"","amount":1,"properties":[{"id":1,"property":"Flying","option":true,"type":"bool","preferred":null},{"id":2,"property":"Rideable","option":true,"type":"bool","preferred":null},{"id":9,"property":"Age","option":"Full Grown","type":"string","preferred":null}]}'

resp = requests.post(f"https://traderie.com/api/adopt_me/listings/create", data=body, headers=headers)

print(resp.text)
```

Comment: You posted the exact same question 2 days ago.

Comment: yeah, and i still can't fix it